# Git: setting external diff tool for graphical files

Tags: git, diff, binaryfiles

I'm trying to get git to open diffed graphical files (images, pdfs, etc) in Preview. The command to open preview is `/usr/bin/open -a Preview file1 file2 …`.

I set up a rule in gitconfig: `git config --global diff.graphical.external ~/.git-diff-graphical.sh` (followed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bkeating/329690)). Then I added some rules to .gitattributes file in `~/.config/git/attributes`:

```
*.jpg    diff=graphical
*.png    diff=graphical
*.gif    diff=graphical
*.pdf    diff=graphical
```

When I check the attributes of a jpg, it says `diff: graphical`, but when I run `git diff` on the file, it opens FileMerge (which I had previously set up as my general external editor). The relevant part of my gitconfig looks like this:

```
[diff]
    external = /Users/me/.git-diff-default.sh
[diff "graphical"]
    external = /Users/me/.git-diff-graphical.sh
```

The order doesn't seem to matter.

**EDIT** If I comment out `external = /Users/me/.git-diff-default.sh` and `[diff "graphical"]`, it opens one of the versions in Preview (it doesn't open the temp file git creates in /var because I think it gets deleted before Preview opens it). So I guess I have 2 problems: opening the temp file and getting git to use the correct diff tool.